# Connection stays open after using dbContext in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, dbcontext, sqlconnection

After I use

```
using (TestDatabaseEntitites ctx = new TestDatabaseEntitites())
{
    ....
}
```

I want all my sql connections to close after the `using` statement and I think that is what's expected. But it doesn't happen. Even after `ctx.Dispose()`.

The only way I can close all the open connections is clearAllPools method.
Am I doing something wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Pooled connections do not physically close, they get reset. That's normal operation of a connections pool and should not affect you if you do everything right.

Comment: Did you implement Dispose in your class TestDatabaseEntitites and close the connection during disposing or after using the sql connection?

Comment: @Jade, the fact that he's using the `using...` code implements Dispose. `using` is `IDisposable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connection pool connections in .Net stay open behind the scenes by design. The reason for this is that opening a connection to the database is generally a very expensive operation which would take literally seconds.

For this reason, closing a connection will only reset it, so that a future `Open` will simply be passed the old reset connection instead of opening a new one.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is referred from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620709/should-i-keep-an-instance-of-dbcontext-in-a-separate-thread-that-performs-period)

DbContext is a very light-weight object.

It doesn't matter whether your DbContext stays alive or you instantiate it just before making the call because the actual DB Connection only opens when you SubmitChanges or Enumerate the query (in that case it is closed on end of enumeration).

In your specific case. It doesn't matter at all.